# C Programming - XOR Bitwise Operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, xor

What operation does the following ‘C’ statement perform?

> star = star ^ 0b00100100;

**(A)** Toggles bits 2 and 5 of the variable star.

**(B)** Clears all bits except bits 2 and 5 of the variable star.

**(C)** Sets all bits except bits 2 and 5 of the variable star.

**(D)** Multiplies value in the variable star with 0b00100100.

I'm still clueless about this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Grumpy response: none, since that won't compile. C doesn't support a `0b` prefix for binary numbers, as standard.

Comment: Really? But this question came out on my past exam paper so I assume it will work though.

Comment: What's the original value of `star`?

Comment: try this : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_bits_manipulation.htm

Comment: @unwind It's a GNU extension.

Comment: @SubSevn Original value of Star isn't giving that is the problem.

Comment: @D3FTY By the way, if you **know** this is the XOR operator, why don't you 1. already know what it does (it's expected from someone doing CS and stuff), 2. if you don't, why don't you google it either?

Comment: Well the operation is XOR, so the result of this operation will be different depending on the input of `star` (think about what operation would do if `star` was 00100100 versus 00100000...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I know it is XOR Operator. I know how it works etc. But I just don't get why the answer is (A). If an intial value of star is given, that'll be easier. In this case, it is not.

Comment: @D3FTY No, it has nothing to do with the initial value of `star`. XOR toggles bits of the LHS where the RHS is 1 and leaves intact the ones where it's 0, **regardless of the starting value** of LHS.

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on how you read "toggles".  Because in that case, you'd best refer to the answer from ivan_pozdeev: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16941428/431415

Answer (score 19, accepted):

XOR operator (also called "logical addition") is defined like this:

```
a   b   a^b
-----------
0   0    0
0   1    1
1   0    1
1   1    0
```

So `a^0` leaves `a` intact while `a^1` toggles it.

For multiple-bit values, the operation is performed bitwise, i.e. between corresponding bits of the operands.

Answer (score 8):

If you know how XOR works, and you know that `^` is XOR in C, then this should be pretty simple. You should know that XOR will flip bits where 1 is set, bits 2 and 5 of 0b00100100 are set, therefore it will flip those bits.

From an "during the test" standpoint, let's say you need to prove this to yourself, you really don't need to know the initial value of `star` to answer the question, If you know how `^` works then just throw anything in there:

```
 00100100
^10101010  (star's made up value)
---------
 10001110  (star's new value)

 bit position: | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0  
               |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---
 star's new v: | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
               |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---
 star's old v: | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0
```

Then check your answers again, did it:

(A) Toggles bits 2 and 5 of the variable star. (Yes)

(B) Clears all bits except bits 2 and 5 of the variable star. (Nope)

(C) Sets all bits except bits 2 and 5 of the variable star. (Nope)

(D) Multiplies value in the variable star with 0b00100100.  (36x170 = 142? Nope)

Answer (score 4):

**It is (A) toggles bits 2 and 5**.

The following is the truth table for the XOR operation:

```
x  y  x^y
0  0   0
1  0   1
0  1   1
1  1   0
```

You can see from the table that `x XOR 0 = x` and `x XOR 1 = !x`.

XOR is a bitwise operation, so it operates on individual bits. Therefore if you XOR `star` with some constant, it will toggle the `1` bits in the constant.

You can find some explanation e.g. [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).

Comment: Any specific explanation to it? I still don't understand it.

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, I'm sorry if I'm dumb. But you can't expect everyone to have the same level of knowledge like you, smart alex. No offense.

Answer (score 3):

The `exclusive OR` has this truth table:

```
A   B   A^B
-----------
1   1   0
1   0   1
0   1   1
0   0   0
```

We can see that if `B` is `true` (`1`) then `A` is flipped (toggled), and if it's `false` (`0`) `A` is left alone.  So the answer is (A).

Comment: How would that make the answer C?

Answer (score 1):

XOR operator returns 0 if both inputs are same otherwise returns 1 if both inputs are different.For Example the Given Truth Table :-

- a=1  b=1 => a^b=0,
- a=0  b=0 => a^b=0,
- a=0  b=1 => a^b=1,
- a=1  b=0 =>    a^b=1.

Answer (score 0):

well xor is binary operator that work on bits of 2 nos.

rule of xoring:for same bit ans is 0 and for different bit ans is 1
let

```
a= 1 0 1 0 1 1
b= 0 1 1 0 1 0
--------------
c= 1 1 0 0 0 1
--------------
```

compare bit of a and b bit by bit 
if same put 0 else put 1
xor is basically used to find the unique in given set of duplicate no.
just xor all nos. and u will get the unique one(if only single unique is present)