# What is the difference between if(x^1!=1) and if(int(x^1)!=1) in C++?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I am trying to find if `x`'s first bit from right is `1`, so I check if the value of `x^1` is `1`. However,

```
int x=6; 
if (x^1!=1)
```

gives wrong answer, but

```
if (int(x^1)!=1)
```

gives the correct answer.

I am not sure why. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Have a lookup on operator precedence.

Comment: Why are you using `^`(bitwise exclusive or) instead of `&` (bitwise and)?  This test doesn't quite do what you think it does.

Comment: Look up what that operator does, you want a bitwise AND not XOR!

Comment: I just realized that In boolean algebra, the `^` symbol is often used as the "AND" operator, so it wasn't that bad a guess.  But you want `&` for bit masking in C++.

Comment: Interesting trivia for *why* the operator precedence is not logical: [Why do bitwise operators have lower priority than comparisons? (Programmers SE)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194635/why-do-bitwise-operators-have-lower-priority-than-comparisons)

Answer (score 13):

It's a trap of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Operator precedence determines how operations are "grouped" (like how `2*3+4` results in the `2*3` being "grouped" together). Adding parentheses changes how things are "grouped" (for example, `2*(3+4)` causes `3+4` to be "grouped" together).

`x^1!=1` is equivalent to `x^(1!=1)`, which can be simplified to `x^0`.

`int(x^1)!=1` is equivalent to `(x^1)!=1` (because you've manually added parentheses here; the `int` part isn't very relevant; it's the parentheses that are important).

As you can see, `x^(1!=1)` and `(x^1)!=1` are not the same.

If your goal is to check the first bit, I might suggest using a bitwise-AND (`&`). You can then just do `if (x & 1)` (but beware, mixing `&` and `==` will result in the same issues as you were having before, so use parentheses if you want to write `if ((x & 1) == 1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Simply, != (Not equal relational operator) has high precedence than ^ (XOR bitwise operator). [Check precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

```
int x=6;
```

**case 1:**  `if (x^1!=1)`

First,  `1!=1 is 0`; then `6^0= 6`. (`110 ^ 000 = 110`); [Check XOR table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941330/c-programming-xor-bitwise-operation)

**Case 2:**  `if (int (x^1)!=1)`

First, `x^1= 7`; then `7!=1 is 1` (true).

Comment: Thanks @Cornstalks you notified right and i rectified it.

Answer (score 0):

@Cornstalks is right with his answer.

I just had that in mind ( it does'nt in fact answer your problem , but can make it more readable) :

Another approach for solving this problem is simply using the modulo operator:

```
if(x%2 == 0)  // then first bit is 0
else  // first bit is 1
```

In the end your task is simply a check for even or odd values.